# Apache Airflow: Some Permissions On New Role Are Reset

Tags: python, airflow, rbac

I am using the RBAC UI in Apache Airflow (version 1.10.6) and wanted to create a custom role for a handful of people to use. I was hoping to restrict their access to a handful of pages, for instance the Documentation and Version pages. I remove several permissions, like `menu access on Documentation`, and then save the role. However, the permissions go back to the way they were almost immediately, like after 5-10 seconds.

I can actually see the permission changes I made on the "List Roles" page before they disappear after refreshing a few times. This does not happen for all the permissions either. Some changes do persist as I would expect, such as `can dag read on <example_dag>`. Is there something I am doing wrong or some setting I missed? Or could this be a bug?

Comment: same on airflow `1.10.10`

Comment: interesting thing is that granting permissions seems to be persistent :/

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. It seems that the Airflow scheduler automatically synchronize the permissions defined at the DAG level using the [`access_control`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.6.3/_api/airflow/models/dag/index.html#airflow.models.dag.DAG) parameter, and remove permissions which are not defined.

You can check the Airflow scheduler logs located in `logs/scheduler/20XX-MM-DD/name_of_your_dag.py` and search for something like:

> Revoking 'can_edit' on DAG 'DAG:name_of_your_dag' for role 'your_role'